# Jogo da Forca - Verificação de acertos

Tags: python

Pessoal estou com um problema para terminar o jogo da froca em Python, eu não estou conseguindo fazer um esquema para verificar se as letras foram acertadas e ou erradas, poderiam me ajudar?

```
from random import randint

lista_palavras = ["casa", "mercado", "palio", "palmeiras", "lakers", "lucas"]

print('''==============================
     JOGO DA FORCA - IFPR
==============================''')
print("\n")

print('''==============================
     Pronto para Começar...?
==============================''')
print("\n")

aceita = 1
n_aceita = 0

while True:
    inicio = int(input("Digite (1) para Inicar ou (0) para Sair: "))

    if inicio == aceita:

        pos= randint (0, len(lista_palavras)-1)
        palavra = lista_palavras[pos]
        riscos = [" _ "] * len(palavra)

        print("\n")
        print("Começando o jogo....FORCA - IFPR")

        erros = 0

        while erros < 7 :
            letra = input("Digite uma letra: ")


            l = 0
            while l < len(palavra):
                if palavra[l] == letra:
                    riscos[l] = letra

                # fazer um esquema para verificar se errou ou acertou

                l+=1

            #se ele errou
            #conta um erro a mais

            #mostrar o desenho conforme a quantidade de erros


        print(palavra)
        print(riscos)

    elif inicio == n_aceita:
        print("Saindo do jogo....")
        print("\n")
        print("Obrigado!")
        break
```

Comment: Você pode fazer: if letra in palavra "Termina a implementação".

Comment: Ok, Matheus, Mais como eu encaixo isso dentro do while?

Comment: Pode ser depois que você pede para digitar uma letra. Você pode fazer: `if letra in palavra: acertos += letra` `else: erros += letra`

Comment: Entendi, mais antes do laço de repetição para percorrer a palavra? Se puder me mostrar um exemplo dentro da estrutura do código eu agradeço, é que sou iniciante em Python então estou aprendendo aos poucos.....kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peguei seu código e mudei algumas coisas, verifique as mudanças e adicione/modifique o que você achar que precisa no seu original.
Edit.: Adicionei comentários pra facilitar a localização das mudanças.

```
from random import randint

lista_palavras = ["casa", "mercado", "palio", "palmeiras", "lakers", 
"lucas"]

print('''==============================
 JOGO DA FORCA - IFPR
==============================''')
print("\n")

print('''==============================
 Pronto para Começar...?
==============================''')
print("\n")

while True:
    inicio = int(input("Digite (1) para Inicar ou (0) para Sair: "))

    '''retirei as variáveis aceita e n_aceita, pois em Python qualquer valor diferente
de 0 já significa verdadeiro, então usei isso como parâmetro para iniciar o jogo'''

    if inicio:

        pos= randint (0, len(lista_palavras)-1)
        palavra = lista_palavras[pos]
        riscos = [" _ "] * len(palavra)

        print("\n")
        print("Começando o jogo....FORCA - IFPR")

        erros = 0

        while erros < 7 :
            letra = input("Digite uma letra: ")

            '''adicionei uma lógica para conferir se a letra está presente na palavra,
        estando presente, ela substitui a posição equivalente dela na string palavra na lista
        de riscos, senão o número de erros aumenta em 1'''

            if letra in palavra:
                pos = palavra.find(letra)
                for i in range(pos, len(palavra)):
                    if letra == palavra[i]:
                        riscos[i] = letra
            else:
                erros += 1

            '''Coloquei a impressão dos riscos dentro do loop para que seja possível
        ver as letras acertadas enquanto se digita novas'''

            print('Palavra:\n', riscos)

        print(palavra)

    else:
        print("Saindo do jogo....")
        print("\n")
        print("Obrigado!")
        break
```

Comment: Ok amigo, obrigado pelos comentários. Porém agora preciso acrescentar o desenho da forca na verificação da letra errada, estou pensando em criar uma def para colocar os erros conforme eu elaborei abaixo, mas quando eu encaixo na verificação apresenta erra no código:

Comment: Qual seria o erro? Como você colocou essas novas funções?

Comment: Então amigo, eu fiz a alteração do código pra vc dar um olhada. O problema agora é que quando eu digito uma letra "errada" não aparece o desenho da forca, e também quando eu digito uma letra não aprece o risco referente a posição da palavra.